# Unknown Japanese encoding in MIDI file

Tags: character-encoding, midi, cjk

I have a MIDI file which I think contains Japanese characters (downloaded from https://www.mediafire.com/file/y8wp3bd7at1agnd/Africa.rar/file).  Unfortunately, none of the MIDI programs I've tried seem to be able to decode the Japanese correctly.

For example, a couple of the instrument names come out as

```
ƒp[ƒJƒbƒVƒ‡ƒ“‚Piƒ}ƒbƒv‚Pj•ƒeƒ“ƒ|�

# hex bytes (from od -t x1)
0000000    c2  83  70  c2  81  5b  c2  83  4a  c2  83  62  c2  83  56  c2
0000020    83  c2  87  c2  83  c2  93  c2  82  50  c2  81  69  c2  83  7d
0000040    c2  83  62  c2  83  76  c2  82  50  c2  81  6a  c2  81  c2  95
0000060    c2  83  65  c2  83  c2  93  c2  83  7c  ef  bf  bd

ƒMƒ^[•‰ŠúÝ’è•‚eD‚n�

# hex bytes (from od -t x1)
0000000    c2  83  4d  c2  83  5e  c2  81  5b  c2  81  c2  95  c2  8f  c2
0000020    89  c2  8a  c3  ba  c2  90  c3  9d  c2  92  c3  a8  c2  81  c2
0000040    95  c2  82  65  c2  81  44  c2  82  6e  ef  bf  bd
```

I used a script to brute-force attempt every conversion `iconv` knows about (thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184565), and I get some results that are *almost* readable using the SHIFT_JISX0213 encoding.

```
ﾂパﾂーﾂカﾂッﾂシﾂδ傔δ督１ﾂ（ﾂマﾂッﾂプﾂ１ﾂ）ﾂ⊊閉テﾂδ督ポ魹ｽ
ﾂギﾂタﾂーﾂ⊊閉渉可甘ｺﾂ静敖津ｨﾂ⊊閉Ｆﾂ．ﾂＯ魹ｽ
```

There are several katakana words visible that are interspersed with ﾂ characters: "Percussion" (パーカッシ), "Map 1"（マップ１）, "Guitar" (ギター).  I don't know how to make sense of the rest of the line (I can't read Japanese so I'm relying on Google Translate).

Does anyone recognize what the correct encoding should be?

Comment: What's the byte sequency for the string you're showing? Because not everything gets rendered as text, so this isn't data that can be reliably used to reproduce your problem (and downloading random data off of mediafire should not be required to answer a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the byte strings above were not present in the original MIDI file. They were mangled by the MIDI reader I was using.

With the help of
[http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Eich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html)
I was able to write a simple C program that extracted the raw bytes , which were in the basic SHIFT-JIS encoding.

```sh
% cc extract_instruments.c -o extract_instruments
% cat AFRICA_55.MID| ./extract_instruments| iconv -f SHIFT-JIS -t UTF8
【  ＡＦＲＩＣＡ　／　ＴＯＴＯ  】   for SC-55      by  染之介
...
```

extract_instruments.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/*
   Acknowledgement:
   ReadVarLen is derived from http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html#BMA2_
   (c) Copyright 1999 David Back.
   EMail: david@csw2.co.uk
   Web: http://www.csw2.co.uk
   This document may be freely copied in whole or in part provided the copy contains
   this Acknowledgement. 
*/
int ReadVarLen() {
   register int value;
   register char c;
   
   if((value = getchar()) & 0x80) {
      value &= 0x7f;
      do {
     value = (value << 7) + ((c = getchar()) & 0x7f);
      } while (c & 0x80);
   }
   
   return(value);
}

void ReadAndPrintName(int length) {
   char name[length+1];
   fgets(name, length+1, stdin);
   printf("%s\n", name);
}

int main() {
   int c1 = 0;
   int c2 = getchar();

   while (c2 != EOF) {
     
     // 0xFF03 == Sequence/Track Name
     if (c1 == 0xff && c2 == 0x03) {
       int length = ReadVarLen();
       ReadAndPrintName(length);
     }
     
     c1 = c2;
     c2 = getchar();
   }

   return 0;
}
```